# Evaporation Rate

Tags: thermodynamics, water, evaporation

I've got a bucket of water in which a heating coil made of copper is submerged with a temperature *Tc* and because of a heating liquid inside the coil, the copper stays at that temperature *Tc*.
How much water (*Tw* = 25°C) can be evaporated per hour per surface area of copper?

Is there a formula to insert different temperatures and area rates of the heater to find the evaporation rate if the water is heated?

**For simplicity:** Airtemperature equals room temperature and the air pressure is 1 atm. The water surface area = 0,06m².

Answer (score 0):

You have to first find out

1. Heat required to convert Tw to Tc using H = Msd(T)
2. Then heat to convert water to vapour by H = mL
3. Then finally using above 2 question and rate give you will be able to find m of water

Comment: An answer was already found. Thanks for the help guys!